# How would I go about building an API converter?

Tags: python, api, serialization, xml-serialization, tastypie

I have multiple different APIs with different schemas serialised in XML or JSON which I need to output as a standardised schema.

Main features needed:

- **Serialisation to XML and JSON**
- **Authentication**

  - I.e.: can't get/set data unless you have the correct user+pass
- **Role/Scope limitation**

  - I.e.: you can't access everything in our database, only what your role allows for
- **Get/set (conversion) between different schemas**

  - I.e.: No matter the input API, you can get it formatted in whichever output API you request

---

Or to put it visually:

Server1 >[send as SOAP 1.1]>[My Server]>[Server3 receives as XML in
Server3 schema]

Server3>[Send as XML]>[My Server]>[Server1 receives as SOAP 1.1 in
Server1 schema]

---

Or to put it programmically:

```
id=MyServer.read.SOAP[Server1.schema](Server1).id
MyServer.send.XML[Server2.schema](data_get(id), Server2)
```

---

It would need to store all received data in a Model (database) so that read is available on-demand.

Is this the sort of problem [Slumber](http://slumber.in/) with [TastyPie](http://tastypieapi.org/) would be best for?

Or are there a different libraries you'd recommend?

Comment: What exactly does 'I.e.: can't get/set data unless you're from a certain DNS' mean?  That smells like something that could be easily bypassed by spoofing ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_address_spoofing ).

Comment: True, sorry, came from the world of internal routing, so proper authentication wasn't the only thing which came to mind. _Question edited_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is harder than it looks for two reasons: 1) SOAP and REST are different paradigms (message passing v's resource based) so there are some things which wont have straightforward mappings, 2) maintainability needs to be built in if any of the APIs involved change.

It definitely makes sense to put in place an intermediate layer service which does the re-routing and also the access control. TastyPie and Slumber help to create the rest API itself, but it seems like you want to also expose a SOAP API in parallel. So you'd probably need something like pysimplesoap or SOAPy onto a common data structure in your intermediate layer. (if you can get rid of the SOAP on the way out your life will be way easier :).).

If the userbase is the same for all the backend services, user-name password might still make sense, but if different people have different rights on different services you might be better off putting something like oAuth in place with an oAuth library and then keeping track of the rights for each user independently.

Comment: Thanks, was just investigating [PySimpleSOAP](http://code.google.com/p/pysimplesoap) and learning [web2py](http://web2py.com) for the problem. Could you expand a little as to the difference in paradigms between [SOAP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOAP) and [REST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/REST)? — I know for certain that I will need to provide both services concurrently from the same data.

Comment: They are really pretty different. SOAP essentially gives you the ability to set up a message pipe down which you can ship arbitrary messages and data objects. WSDL specifications are used to define all these types. This is flexible but it allows you to create patterns which REST will not support. REST is based on HTTP primitives and gives you 7-8 top level operations with known semantics, so in some ways it's more restrictive than SOAP, on the other hand there is no real equivalent of the tight binding of WSDL specs (there are frameworks like Swagger, WADL etc. but not widely used yet).

Comment: Hmm, was just reading the [WSDL wiki article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Services_Description_Language), found it a little ambiguous what with REST controllers being built into the example... so would SOAP be primarily used for transferring binary information, and REST be used for transferring textual information? - But then again that wouldn't make sense, since everything SOAP transfers is in XML format... can you please alleviate my confusion?

Comment: Both can be used for both - the REST / SOAP choice is often due to "history" in the company or what they are precisely trying to achieve. If you're trying to achieve a heavy duty "compiled" binding between the web services, the SOAP+XML is the way to go because WSDL gives you tight specs. However, if your API is going to be consumed in the browser or on Mobile Phones then REST+JSON is likely better - it plugs into Javascript 1000x more easily and is simpler to code against.